# How to create striped progressbar in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I need to create striped progress bar in android.How to create a one like below.

[image]

I saw the example on bootstrap but i don't know how to implement that in my app.

Comment: see https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you may wish to try this [Bootstrap Progress Bar](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/wiki/Bootstrap-Progress-Bar) ,

and use  `app:striped="true"` like below

```
<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:animated="true"
    app:bootstrapBrand="warning"
    app:progress="78"
    app:striped="true"
    />
```

Please follow the [guild lines](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap) given by them.

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:{X.X.X}'
 }
```

`{X.X.X}` = latest library version which is 2.3.1

More over

You should also override your application class with the following:

```
 public class SampleApplication extends Application {
     @Override public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         TypefaceProvider.registerDefaultIconSets();
     }
 }
```

and it works for me!

## **Note** :

Given example was the default one and it won't work unless you change the `app:progress="78"` to  `app:bootstrapProgress="78"` .

Comment: what about dependency?I added below dependency.But no luck

Comment: compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:25.1.0'

Comment: @m.v.n.kalyani in that xml view add `app:striped="true"`

Comment: `compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.3.1'` you have given something else its not your compile version but that library version available!  
@m.v.n.kalyani

Comment: i will check,thanak you

Comment: Error:(18) No resource identifier found for attribute 'progress' in package 'com.example.dvelopselvam.bootstrap'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136847/discussion-between-charu-and-m-v-n-kalyani).

Comment: @Charuක hi bro . please check this if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208077/android-java-quering-in-parse-database

Comment: Is it possible to set it's progress programatically in java?